# Filter query inside query in Django views

Tags: python, django

I m working on hotel reservation app, in which i have a model for "RoomType" that contains a field for number of available rooms per day ...

I created a new model For Saving BookedDates (from, to), with ForiegnKey for the RoomType model...

Every time the user books a room (from, to), a signal will be sent the RoomType model to be saved in ManyToManyField in it ...

*Now the end users will search for available rooms in specific date(from, to)*

So i created a query to filter rooms available in this dates and to check if it is reserved in the specific date more times than the numberOfAvailableRoom per day..

**My Problem Is** that when i make a query to filter RoomTypes i .exclude() through it A Query For BookedDates models in which numberOfAvailableRoom per day field is less than number of time specific room is booked in that date ... 
but actually the result of this excludes any roomType that is booked in BookedDates models!

models.py

```
class BookedDates(models.Model):
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    room_type = models.ForeignKey(
        'RoomType', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    booked_from = models.DateField(null=True)
    booked_to = models.DateField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} /\ {} /\ {}'.format(self.room_type, self.hotel, self.booked_from)


class RoomType(models.Model):
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room_type = models.ForeignKey(RoomTypesNames, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bookedDates = models.ManyToManyField(
        BookedDates)
    number_of_rooms = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

views.py

```
            roomsByDate = RoomType.objects.annotate(modulo=numAdult % F('room_capacity')).filter(
                q_city, q_room_capacity1, modulo=0
            ).exclude(number_of_rooms__lte = BookedDates.objects.filter(room_type=F('room_type'), 
              booked_from__in = day).count())  ## my error is that the exclude , excludes any room type in the BookedDates model, even if it is reserved in this date number of times less than number_of_rooms available per day
```

*Any Another Approach For Creating This Query In The Right Way Will Be Welcome*
**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks For** @schillingt

> updating for his answer, Actually when i search by the related_name for the model, the query filters the times of its existence in the other BookedDates model regardless to the date_from query in that model ...
>   So,
>   I made the query through the ManyToManyField itself to count times of thay bookedDates field only

```
roomsByDate = RoomType.objects.annotate(
    modulo=numAdult % F('room_capacity')
).filter(
    q_city, q_room_capacity1, modulo=0
).annotate(
    times_booked=Count("bookedDates ", filter=Q(booked_from__in=day), distinct=True)
).exclude(
    number_of_rooms__lte=F('times_booked')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need another annotation to calculate the number of bookings for that room. You can make use of the reverse foreign key path / related_name which in this case is `roomtype_set` I think.

```
roomsByDate = RoomType.objects.annotate(
    modulo=numAdult % F('room_capacity')
).filter(
    q_city, q_room_capacity1, modulo=0
).annotate(
    times_booked=Count("roomtype_set__id", filter=Q(booked_from__in=day), distinct=True)
).exclude(
    number_of_rooms__lte=F('times_booked')
)
```

Comment: Thanks A lot .. It Worked Well

Comment: Please, Why this  ; distinct=True ?

Comment: I've found sometimes that the aggregation will count items multiple times. It's occasionally not needed, but I haven't spent the time to truly determine when it's needed. Or I have bugs crop up when I make changes to the code later on and miss that count.